# Solving the congruence $3x \equiv 17 \pmod{29}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

The given linear congruence is to be solved:

$$\gcd:(3;29)=1 |17$$
$$3x+29y=1 \iff 3x \equiv 1 \pmod{29} \iff y \equiv 3^{-1} \pmod{29}$$

With the extended Euclidean algorithm one obtains:
\begin{align*}
29 & = 3 \cdot 9+2\\
3 & = 2 \cdot 1+1\\
2 & = 2 \cdot 1
\end{align*}

By means of backward resolution:
\begin{align*}
1 & = 3-2 \cdot 1\\
  & = -29+10 \cdot 3\\
  & = -29+10(3-29)\\
  & = 10 \cdot 3-1 \cdot 29
\end{align*}

$-1 \equiv 3^{-1} \pmod{29}$

$$\implies 3x \equiv 17 \pmod{27} \iff x \equiv -1 \cdot 3x \pmod{29} \equiv -1 \cdot 17 \pmod{29}$$

Are my considerations correct so far and how do I arrive at the solution $x$?

Comment: This is hard to follow. What does "$gcd:(3;29)=1|17$" mean?   And $29$ is not equal to either $3\times9 +23$ nor $2\times 1$.   In any case, isn't the inverse of $3\pmod {29}$ obviously $10$?

Comment: gcd(3,29)=1|17 mean that the result 1 divides the number 17, which is why the task can be solved at all.

Comment: You meant to write $\implies 3x \equiv 17 \pmod{29}$ .

Comment: Writing run on equations is always confusing.  $(3,29)$ is not equal to $1|17$ in any sense so don't write an equality between them.  In any case, as I mentioned, the inverse of $3\pmod {29}$ is $10$ by inspection, no Euclidean algorithm needed.  But your application of that algorithm does confirm $10$ as the inverse, not $-1$.

Comment: This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The easiest solution is to recognize that $17\equiv -12 \bmod 29$ immediately yielding $x\equiv -4 \equiv 25 \bmod 29$

Comment: See the linked dupes for most all known methods.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly applied the extended Euclidean algorithm to show that $1 = 10 \cdot 3 - 1 \cdot 29$.  However, this does not imply that $-1$ is the multiplicative inverse of $3$ modulo $29$.  Observe that
$$1 \equiv 10 \cdot 3 - 1 \cdot 29 \equiv 10 \cdot 3 \pmod{29}$$
since $1$ and $10 \cdot 3$ differ by a multiple of $29$.  Hence, $3^{-1} \equiv 10 \pmod{29}$.

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
3x & \equiv 17 \pmod{29}\\
10 \cdot 3x & \equiv 10 \cdot 17 \pmod{29}\\
x & \equiv 170 \pmod{29}\\
x & \equiv 5 \cdot 29 + 25 \pmod{29}\\
x & \equiv 25 \pmod{29}
\end{align*}

**Check:** If $x \equiv 25 \pmod{29}$, then $3x \equiv 3 \cdot 25 \equiv 75 \equiv 2 \cdot 29 + 17 \equiv 17 \pmod{29}$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque  Do you consider all linear congruences with prime moduli to be duplicates?  The reason I answered this question was to address the specific mistake the OP made.

Comment: In fact even that mistake itself is a duplicate.